# Strategies for Rich Text with an Angular Material project

Tags: angular-material

I am making an appplication in Angular using Material that uses Dynamic Components.

At the moment I have a simple text component, you set `mat-body-1` as the type and `data` to `Hello kind people`, so it may have a json structure like so:

```
{
   selector: "app-text",
   type: "mat-body-1",
   data: "Hello kind people"
}
```

Forgive the psudeo code here but what is needed seems to be something richer:

```
{
   selector: "app-text",
   data: "`<p mat-body-1>Hello <style color=red>kind</style> <b>people</b></p>`"
}
```

Here is my concerns which may be unfounded:

1. `innerHTML` isn't amazing.
2. Putting DOM strings into JSON seems unclean.

**Is there a more improved strategy for displaying rich text in Angular Material?**